# How to run a node.js application in vert.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vert.x

I'm totally new to vert.x and I'm trying to see if it's possible to bring up an existing nodejs application in vert.x. Following the instructions at http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x3-says-hello-to-npm-users/, I used npm to install vert.x. I can run a simple hello-world app, but running our existing app is proving to be a little challenging. All the vert.x docs I've found talk about writing new apps, not porting existing code.

Oh, and the same code base needs to continue running on existing nodejs systems.

The trouble that I'm seeing is that vert.x won't load nodejs native modules correctly. For example, Vert.x choked on this `require`:

```
var fs = require("fs");
```

After a little searching I found the vert.x equivalent:

```
var fs = require("vertx-js/file_system");
```

Perhaps we could create an shim/abstraction layer to wrap the differences. I did a quick one for the file system API and it seems to load correctly. It does seem like writing an entire abstraction layer will be a fair bit of work. But it seems like it would solve the compatibility issue for APIs used within our source.

The real trouble is how to intercept all the `require` statements in the `node_modules` directories. Those modules are also going to be requiring lots of other native APIs like the file-system. This seems like a problem that others may have encountered and solved already. Better not to re-invent the wheel.

I could roll my own solution. I don't really want to sed/replace the node_module source except as a last resort. The only other alternative I have thought of is creating a directory of abstractions an inserting that directory name at the head of the NODE_PATH. This solution seems like it might work, but as I mentioned I'm a vert.x noob so I cannot forsee what kinds of pitfalls lie along that approach.

Does vert.x support a shim layer for running nodejs applications?

Comment: I think you can try [es4x](https://github.com/reactiverse/es4x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short version TLDR**:

> You can't!

**Long version**:

Vert.x is not a Node.JS replacement or runtime. Although there are quite similarities and common design choices such as support for `CommonJS` modules and support for `NPM` the native libraries are not present. All `I/O` operations in Vert.x are done using Vert.x API and they do not always relate to the Node counter parts.

Also you should be aware that the JavaScript language version is not the same either, for example Node relies on V8 which nowadays is quite close to fully support `ECMA2015` or `ES6` for short, Vert.x as a framework running on the JVM relies on Nashorn (the JavaScript runtime from the JDK itself) which is still on `ES5`.

The idea of supporting NPM in Vert.x was not to emulate Node but to allow the usage of many of its modules (that do not depend on node native modules). For that reason there is a warning on the [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/). But I guess it is not clear.

There are some ways to get most out of NPM and Vert.x, one option is to go 100% ES6 and use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile back to ES5 which will run fine both with Node and Vert.x (until the moment you use a native module).

If you must to use Node, say that you already have an application built on node and the port is not worth (in terms of resouces/time/etc) then I'd suggest to look into the [tcp eventbus bridge](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge). This bridge will allow your existing application to produce and consume messages of an existing cluster of vert.x applications.

Comment: Paulo, I appreciate your answer. This confirms what I was thinking. I did miss that warning in the docs. The challenge we're facing is that we cannot run V8 because . . . well, long story. So moving to vert.x will require a significant amount of rework, but it's better than rewriting from scratch. Thanks for your help!